# Java SpringMVC OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

We have deployed the java war file in server, the application is hosted in Tomcat webserver.

While loading the application we are getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError issue which makes the application stop.

We  are using Java version 8 and Tomcat version 8.

Attached error details, please let me know if any configuration needs to be verified?

```
SEVERE [28] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run Unexpected death of background thread [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

```
SEVERE [76] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundaException: -20
at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:252)
at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:535)
at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.access$400(NativePRNG.java:331)
at sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:220)
at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:468)
at sun.security.util.KeyUtil.checkTlsPreMasterSecretKey(KeyUtil.java:268)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineUnwrap(RSACipher.java:480)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.unwrap(Cipher.java:2553)
at sun.security.ssl.RSAKeyExchange$RSAPremasterSecret.decode(RSAKeyExchange.java:185)
at sun.security.ssl.RSAC1ientKeyExchange$RSAClientKeyExchangeConsumer.consume(RSAClientKeyExchange.java:285) 
at sun.security.ssl.ClientKeyExchange$ClientKeyExchangeConsumer.consume(ClientKeyExchange.java:110)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444) 
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:968)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:955)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:902)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.tasks(SecureNioChannel.java:423)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:483) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:238)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpointSocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1475)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExcutor.java:624) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run (TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for <0x0000000642344808> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject) 
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

```
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-71 #120 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000071509c004000 nid=0x48b1 waiting on condition [0x00007150129f000] 
java lang Thread State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
-parking to wait for <0x0000000642344808> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175) 
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java.2039)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue java:442) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:103)
at org apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:31)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.get.Task(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
at java util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I have no experience with tomcat, but I get something very similar when deploying war to wildfly server (it is also outOfMemoryException). I guess solution is similar also, try finding how to increase memory allocated for tomcat. Also for me it happens when I do multiple deployments/redeployments while not restarting the machine so just a simple machine restart often also fixes it

Comment: There is far too little information here. If you get excessive GC you are producing too much garbage. So it must be something in your code or a framework you are using. But with the details here that will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Thank you Vojin, we have increased the RAM size, the issue is solved.